# An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.NETCore.App.deps.json) was not found

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Two months ago i had done an .Net 5 web Api that worked fine, today I'm updating my entities and when i add a new migration appeared an error : An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.NETCore.App.deps.json) was not found: package: 'runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version: '5.0.9-servicing.21359.8'
path: 'runtimes/win-x64/lib/net5.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'

I have been searching but i have not found anything, I supposed to add some package or do I miss something ?
I'm using .net 5, Entity framework core, Visual studio 2019

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Visiting https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64/ does not show version `5.0.9-servicing.21359.8` as available. Most likely because it is a pre-release version that has been removed since the official release of `5.0.9`.

Cleaning your working directory and updating to version `5.0.9` should fix this.

Answer (score -1):

For me to slove this problem :
Uninstall and Install the package from NuGet
Also you can upgrade the package
it's working for me

Answer (score -1):

Even after one year, the issue still persists.
For me, the version showing error was `version: '6.0.11'`, although my .NET Core version was 6.
There has been only one workaround I found to fix this. 
**Update the .NET Core version(to latest if possible(recommended)), 

and change Target version of Solution in Settings.**

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by updating the runtime, I downloaded it on this page https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet this worked for me